# How to create multiple store?

Tags: multistore

Am using magento 1.9.2.3. I want to use the same theme but use different categories and products by creating seperate store. I referred  [This link](http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-setup-manage-multiple-stores-in-magento-commerce/)

In that I gave the url as `http://127.0.0.1/magento/mystore2.com/` in secure and unsecure url option. But when I open the site with this url, I am getting the default category from my old store. And my old store url is `http://127.0.0.1/magento`
Somebody kindly guide me and tell me where have I went wrong?

Comment: did you copy index.php to mystore2.com/ folder?

Comment: why you need to copy files??? just use store code and type... omg

Comment: and change base url per store view..

Comment: should I create any folder specifically for the new store in theme file?